# How can automate the input to a program with Perl?

Tags: perl, input

The program has these prompts:

```
Enter Username:
Enter Code:
```

How can I get Perl to input the proper text for each prompt?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm). There's a [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Expect) for it.

Comment: Err … did someone downvote this for not using pretty linking and not using the permalink? Aside form those differences, this answer is the same as mine.

Answer (score 3):

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm) is the usual solution.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.